# Unexpected Result in Regex

Tags: python, regex

```
pattern = r'[ -\\[\\]]'
regex = re.compile(pattern)
name = '123[ shiv'
new_name = regex.sub('_',name)
```

gives result(new_name) ::

```
'_____shiv'
```

instead of::

```
'123__shiv'
```

..thanx in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex is creating a range from `whitespace` *(ASCII Code - 32)* to `opening bracket - [`*(ASCII Code - 91)* because of that `-` in between. And that range includes the numbers `0 to 9` *(ASCII Code - 48 to 57)*.

You need to change your regex to: -

```
pattern = '[- \\[\\]]'
```

Moved `-` at the beginning.

Comment: thanx for quick reply.. :) can't up vote ur answer .. dont have enough  reputations .. :(

Comment: Actually, I think it's creating a range from space to backslash (it's in a raw string).